# *the counter* to reverse an array using pointers doesn't work

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

int i;

int vector[5]={6,17,28,39,410},*r;  //variables declaration
r=(int*)&vector;            //pointer declaration


for (i = 0; i<5;i++){           //print the array in using a loop
printf("%d ",vector[i]);
}

printf("\n\n");

for(i=0;i<5;i++){           //print the array in reverse order using a loop
vector[i] = *(r+4-i);           //it should be from the last to the first but it prints it 
    printf("%d ",vector[i]);    //differently, see below
}

return 0;}
```

It should be:

```
6 17 28 39 410
410 39 28 17 6
```

but it results in:

```
6 17 28 39 410
410 39 28 39 410
```

the last two should be 17 6

Comment: Please be clear about what is needed. Should you reverse the array in memory or just print in the reverse order ? Also if printing in reverse order then just decrement the index like `for (i = 4; i = 0;i--){           //print the array in using a loop
printf("%d ",vector[i]);
}`

Comment: Based on your question, IMO answer provided by `unwind` is the one to be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

int i;

int vector[5]={6,17,28,39,410},*r; //variables declaration
r=(int*)&vector;            //pointer declaration


for (i = 0; i<5;i++){           //print the array in using a loop
printf("%d ",vector[i]);
}

printf("\n\n");

for(i=0;i<5;i++){           //print the array in reverse order using a loop
          //it should be from the last to the first but it prints it 
    printf("%d ",*(r+4-i));    //differently, see below
}
return ( 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are overwriting the data you're trying to read, before reading it.

Just write out the steps your code is taking manually, and you'll see it.

To do reversal in-place, you must swap values around, to avoid overwriting.

Also note that the name of an array evaluates to a pointer to the first argument, in the proper context. So this:

```
r=(int*)&vector;
```

is *much* better written as just:

```
r = vector;
```

You should really avoid casts, and your cast is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are changing the first two values. So first two steps Your array
will be like this.

```
410 39 28 39 410
```

After that loop continues it will get that replaced value. You can store the replaced value in the another array.

```
for(i=0,j=4;i<j;i++,j--){
            temp=vector[i]; // storing the value in  temporary variable
            vector[i] = r[j]; 
            r[j]=temp; // assigning the value .
    }
    for ( i=0;  i < 5 ; i ++ )
            printf("%d\n",vector[i]);
```